# Simple v-model not disappearing when false

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i'm having a little problem with my code, i think it's a simple problem but i'm having a hard time to figure it out, maybe you guys could lend me a hand!

So i have a  that i have to show on/off when the user clicks on the button, i've already did the same thing in other projects before, but for some reason, the v-model:"table" or the @click="table = !table" are not working! i keep clicking at the button but does not seens to work at all, the table keeps showing static. I will leave here a screenshot of the table/btn and the code (template and script).

Thank you guys so much in advance!

[image]

CODE:

```
          v-model="dialog"
          fullscreen
        >
          <v-card>
            
            <v-app-bar color="#39a0ed" dark>
            <v-card-title>Menu Analista</v-card-title>
             <v-btn
                text
                class="white justify-end"
                color="#32322c"
                @click="dialog = false"
              >
                Fechar
              </v-btn>
            </v-app-bar>
             
         
             
                <v-btn @click="table = !table" >Visualizar</v-btn>
                <v-btn class="primary" elevation="10" >Pesquisar Cadastro</v-btn>
                <v-btn class="primary" elevation="10" >Erros de Cadastro ( 2 )</v-btn>  
                         
                    
  
            <v-data-table :value="true" :headers="headers" :items="infos" item-key="email" v-model="table" ></v-data-table>
                       
                     

            <v-img
            src="../assets/analyst1.svg"
            style="max-width:500px; right:-75%;"
            >

            </v-img>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>

             
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>


<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { db, auth } from '../services/firebase';
import logo1 from '../assets/logo1.png'
import axios from 'axios'
import Table1 from './Table1'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
        dialog: false,       
        hidden: false,
        drawer: false,
        table: false, 
        name: null, 
        email: null,
        photoURL: null,
        sector: null,
        position: null,
        client: null,
        clientlogo: null,     
        infos: null,

        headers: [
      {
        text: "Email",
        align: "center",
        value: "email",
      },
          
        ]
     } },
     
     mounted () {
        axios
          .get('http://localhost:5566/users')
          .then(response => (this.infos = response.data.rows))

},

 computed: {
      headersList() {
        return this.headers
      },
      userList() {
        return this.infos
      }
      
  } 
 


}
</script>
```